# How can I reduce number of categories in a vector by number of observations?

Tags: r, categorical-data

I have a column with the County. Since there are over 1,000 different counties, a lot of these aren't credible. What I want to do is either select the top n counties by the number of observations and bucket the rest in an "Other" category.

After trying models with that methodology, I'll explore doing different clustering techniques.

Comment: `forcats::fct_lump` is specifically for this: https://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_lump.html

Comment: @JonSpring, thanks! Exactly what I was looking for!